# Reverse the search in cycle graph prolog

Tags: prolog

I've got this problem with a prolog program, since i'm a complete beginner i thought i'd come here for some answers or help.

This is my database:

```
road(hoor,horby).
road(horby,lund).
road(horby,sjobo).
road(lund,sjobo).
road(sjobo,tomelilla).
road(sjobo,ystad).
road(tomelilla,ystad).
road(ronne,gudhjem).
```

Then these are my rules:

```
:- op(150, xfy, to).

X to Y :-
    findall(Waypoint, get_waypoints(X,Y,Waypoint), Waypoints),
    write(Waypoints).

get_waypoints(Start, End, []) :- 
    road(Start, End).
get_waypoints(Start, End, [Waypoint|Result]) :-
    road(Start, Waypoint),
    get_waypoints(Waypoint, End, Result).
```

It works fine when i for example ask

```
?- horby to ystad.
```

The output then becomes:

```
[[lund,sjobo],[lund,sjobo,tomelilla],[sjobo],[sjobo,tomelilla]]
true.
```

Which is perfect. But lets say i want to find the path from ?- ystad to horby. 
When i ask for this it only gives me:

```
[]
true.
```

What are some ways that i can implement to fix this problem?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The short answer is that if you have a road from `X` to `Y`, then, implicitly, you have a road from `Y` to `X`, but your Prolog rules don't know that. You can add the symmetry to your Prolog code, but you'll need to watch for circular routes.

Comment: Minor: don't define your own operators as a starter.

Comment: Can you justify the [tag:hamiltonian-cycle] tag? From the description of the problem it seems that is a simple cycle, not a Hamiltonian circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using the roads in both directions**

The problem is that your roads are one-way only. You need to use them both ways.

You can do that by adding a new rule:

```
connected(X, Y):- road(X, Y) ; road(Y, X).
```

Now, if you just replace `road(Start, Waypoint)` with `connected(Start, Waypoint)`, you search now in all directions, but your predicate `get_waypoints` will yield infinite number of solutions as it may go back and forth between cities.

**Checking if a city was already visisted**

You need to check if a city you visit hasn't been visited before. You can do that using a list (an accumulator) of the cities you visited so far:

```
get_waypoints(Start, End, Waypoints):-
    get_waypoints(Start, End, [Start], Waypoints).

get_waypoints(Current, End, Acc, Waypoints):-
    connected(Current, End),
    reverse(Acc, [_|Waypoints]).

get_waypoints(Current, End, Acc, Waypoints):-
    connected(Current, Waypoint),
    Waypoint \== End,
    \+ member(Waypoint, Acc),
    get_waypoints(Waypoint, End, [Waypoint|Acc], Waypoints).
```

The subgoal `Waypoint \== End` ensures that once you reached the destination, you won't further build on that path. `\+ member(Waypoint, Acc)` makes sure you don't visit the same city twice.

Because you need to check if you don't return to the starting city, the accumulator will contain that too. That's way, in the end, when the accumulator is reversed, the first element (the starting city) is discarded: `reverse(Acc, [_|Waypoints])`.

**An example query**

```
| ?- ystad to horby.
[[sjobo],[sjobo,lund],[tomelilla,sjobo],[tomelilla,sjobo,lund]]

yes
```

**Update: including start and end nodes in the resulting list (requested in comments)**

To include the start city and the end city in the result along with the waypoints, it is sufficient to add the `End` node to the accumulator in the first rule for `get_waypoints/2`:

```
get_waypoints(Current, End, Acc, Waypoints):-
    connected(Current, End),
    reverse([End|Acc], Waypoints]).
```

Comment: Thank you so much Berariu! This worked perfectly, i appriciate your answer a lot!

Comment: I have one question regarding the `reverse`. When it reaches `reverse`it has the Acc of `[horby, hoor]` and sets the `Waypoints` to `horboy` could you please explain a litte more in depth what it does. I have a hard time understanding it when i use the debugger.
Thank you!

Comment: The accumulator has two *functional* roles: (1) iteratively build the solution (the intermediate nodes between the start node and the end node); (2) contain the list of the nodes that have been visited (so you can avoid visiting the same city multiple times). For the first objective you don't need the starting node, but for the second you do. Now, the accumulator contains the visited nodes in reversed order. When the destination node is reached you need to: (1) reverse the accumulator; (2) discard the starting node (which now becomes the head of the reversed accumulator).

Comment: In your case, you started from `hoor`, passed through `horby` and reached the destination (can't tell which that is). So, the accumulator is `[horby, hoor]`, containing both the starting node and the waypoints. First you reverse that to get the cities in the order they were visited: `[hoor, horby]`. Since the first element, `hoor` is the starting node, you don't need it, so you take only the tail of that list: `[horby]` (only the waypoints).

Comment: This made much more sense to me now! Thank you once again man for your help, you saved me much time and gave me a lot of knowledge in short time!

Comment: I have one last question sir. If i want to in the end print out the whole route, including the start and end cities, how would i do that, i've tried to append wih `append(X,[Waypoints|Y],Way),
write(Way). but it doesn't work, do you have any sugestions on how to solve that?
Thank you!